# Tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503 , ECONNRESET

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, sockets

We're using an Angular JS application. For a particular user login, we're seeing the following error stack trace in the node server logs.

Login API invoked for xxxxxxxxx

Requesting REST URL FOR  xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx login

Requesting REST URL FOR  xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxx

Login API : xxxxxxxxx

Error [top] while trying to login:  tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503

Unknown Error during login

{ Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=503
    at ClientRequest.onConnect (/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxx/node_modules/tunnel-agent/index.js:165:19)

```
at ClientRequest.g (events.js:292:16)
at emitThree (events.js:116:13)
at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:194:7)
at Socket.socketOnData (_http_client.js:394:11)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:176:18)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:134:10)
at TCP.onread (net.js:547:20) code: 'ECONNRESET' }
```

We're trying to authenticate the user by constructing the REST url at the application layer and hitting the concerned api.
The login works fine if we're hitting the api through PostMan. Moreover, the issue is happening only for a certain user and not for everyone.

Comment: You're probably sending a malformed request, or your backend code is broken. You're getting a 503 service unavailable back from the server you're connecting to, if you send the request manually through your browser, does it work?

Comment: @BobDole If by 'sending the request manually through your browser' , you mean hitting the backend REST url through application like PostMan, then yes, through that the user is able to login.

Comment: Have you confirmed that both requests send the same data and use the same method to the URI? It sounds like something is malformed in your application and the request isn't going through with the same information.

Comment: @BobDole - The only data that we're sending are the user credentials. We've verified they're the same. We're using a POST call for user login. Infact we're printing the URI in the server logs and it is same as what we're using through PostMan for log in

Comment: Can you make a very basic HTML form on a client PC and send the same POST data to the same host and see what the response is? It might be that you're logging in successfully but the next part of your app is failing to proceed.